# Image from innerHTML is not showing up in dist folder when I do $yarn prod

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, yarnpkg

I have this js code:

```
const checkEmptyState = () => {
  if (typeof $orders == 'undefined' || $orders.length <= 0) {
    const $orderList = document.querySelector('.orders');
      const $div = document.createElement(`div`);
      $div.classList.add(`emptystate`);
      $div.innerHTML =`
      <img srcset="./src/assets/img/coffee-maker.png 67w, ./src/assets/img/coffee-maker@2x.png" 134w" sizes="67px, 134px" src="./src/assets/img/coffee-maker.png" alt="A coffee maker"/>
      <span class="emptystate__content">
        Please order something
        <span role="img" aria-label="Drunk emoji">
          
        </span>
      </span>
    `;
    $orderList.appendChild($div);
  }
}
```

When I run `$yarn dev` the image is showing up in my `localhost:`. The problem is that if I deploy the website or run `$yarn prod` the image is not showing up in the `dist` folder, so the image won't show up on the web page.

Comment: Stil doesn't show up

Comment: press F12 to see where it expects to find them and then remove from the beginning of the url

Comment: `/src/assets/img/coffee-maker.jpg`

Comment: What is the URL of the page itself? I bet `/assets/page` or `/page`

Comment: Try removing the leading dot then

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.